# Using modern Azure AD B2C Library to get an access token for API pass through

Tags: access-token, azure-ad-b2c

It seems to me in the recent docs that Azure AD B2C with the V2 user flows is advertised as working straight out of the box but all you get for ASP.NET Core Web App --> API with JWT Bearer authoristion are some poor Postman examples and a bunch of confusing, outdated docs and code examples.

Using the common auth mechanics below to connect to an Azure B2C tenant as the IdP, is it possible to request an access token from the Azure B2C provider without having to go through the more convoluted MSAL or ADAL library authorisation routes? If not, then after days of searching, I am yet to find a single clear example detailing this simple flow. Even the GitHub examples are littered with stale, unaddressed issues and many non MS pull requests.

```
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
```

Surely this is a very common and almost mandatory scenario these days and as such could easily be integrated into the code flow with the newer Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI libraries?

UPDATE 1

As an example, when testing a different IdP such as Auth0, it will retrieve an access token for any requested API audiences straight out of the box even using the authorization code flow with minimal extra code.

Why is this not possible in Azure AD B2C considering it's such a common pattern to access a protected resource these days? Is this on the B2C V2 roadmap?

Comment: I'm sorry that the documentation experience has been bad. We are actively working to improve it. Can you please provide the docs that you're referring to that you're having issues with? I'll look into them and see if we can clarify these issues. I'm currently looking into this to see if I can get a code sample utilizing services.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone ahead and forked an existing old sample and updated it accordingly. This sample will work to get an access token from a B2C tenant.

Please see : https://github.com/FrankHu-MSFT/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi

I've tested it using a V2 B2C sample policy and it will automatically redirect to JWT.MS to show the access token that you just received.

You'll be able to find the configureservices method defined in the startup.cs

Per the code :

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
          services.AddAuthentication(options =>
          {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          })
            .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
            {
              jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
              jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
              jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
              {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
              };
            });

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

You'll need to update the appsettings and index.cshtml file per the new step 5 :https://github.com/FrankHu-MSFT/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi#optional-step-5-configure-the-sample-with-your-app-coordinates

Does this answer your question? If there's something missing please comment and let me know.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for taking the time to respond and I appreciate you making the effort to update that repo. Unfortunately I was referring to the Web Client doing it's initial auth request in for example an implicit flow and it returning the id_token and access_token without having to use the poor MSAL/ADAL approach. Not the API side of things. The code you've produced pretty much does the same as this standard API code: `services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));`.

Comment: See UPDATE 1 comment above.

Comment: So what code are you trying to utilize? Are you trying to make manual get/post calls to the authorize and token endpoints? Something similar to this git for AAD? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect It is much simpler to utilize MSAL/ADAL.

Comment: I was attempting to use the latest ASP.NET Core 2.2/3.0 preview libraries. The objective was to not have to run around manually while digging through outdated example repos. The example you just pointed to was for .NET framework and was just to for an API to grab a token from AAD. My question was asking about Azure AD B2C, with ASP.NET Core for WebClient to API.
Doesn't matter anymore, looks like I'll be using Auth0 going forward (for the above mentioned reasons). Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I will be forwarding this information back to the Product Group who handles the B2C in regards to this to improve our B2C product to meet the business standards that you need. Best of luck with Auth0 and hopefully you're able to get what you need going that route.